# File ended while scanning the use of \frac

Tags: errors, syntax

I'm sure I made a mistake here somewhere, which didn't allow me to compile the PDF file in order to see what I'm doing. Sure enough, I've been looking at the `\frac`, trying to catch some rule violation, but there seems to be none! If you wish to contribute to make this equation beautiful, that helps too!

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\label{key}
E_{k,k}&=&\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathcal{B}_{x}^{\left(e\right)}
    +\mathcal{B}_{y}^{\left(e\right)}\right]J\left(J+1\right)
    +\left(\mathcal{B}_{z}^{\left(e\right)}-\frac{1}{2}
  \left[\mathcal{B}_{x}^{\left(e\right)}
       +\mathcal{B}_{y}^{\left(e\right)}\right]\right)\kappa^{2}  \\
E_{k\pm2,k}&=&\frac{1}{4}[\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}-\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]
    {[J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)]\times[J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)(k\pm2)]}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Comment: Put this snippet in a small document with your preamble and no other text in the body. If it shows the error you can post this complete test document (try to shorten the preamble), if not the error is somewhere else.

Comment: I have no problem except the second line  is too long.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem? Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That's because you've forgotten "}"!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to generate the error message you say you're getting. I would like to suggest, though, that you rewrite some of the code to use `\left` and `\right` much more sparingly than you do at present. If you compare the LaTeX codes for the first and second groups of equations, you will hopefully agree that the second group's code is much simpler and easier to read.

A separate comment: The `IEEEeqnarray` environment is extremely powerful and flexible. However, at present you don't really seem to be making use of the package's machinery. You may therefore wish to look into making use of the simpler `align` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package. As the second and third groups of equations in the following screenshot demonstrate, the output is identical -- though, arguably, the syntax of the `align` environment is simpler.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for 'IEEEeqnarray' env.
\usepackage{geometry,amsmath}
\begin{document}

OP's original form
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\label{key1}
E_{k,k}&=&\frac{1}{2}\left[\mathcal{B}_{x}^{\left(e\right)}+
    \mathcal{B}_{y}^{\left(e\right)}\right]J\left(J+1\right)+
    \left(\mathcal{B}_{z}^{\left(e\right)}-\frac{1}{2}
    \left[\mathcal{B}_{x}^{\left(e\right)}+\mathcal{B}_{y}^{\left(e\right)}
    \right]\right)\kappa^{2}  \\
E_{k\pm2,k}&=&\frac{1}{4}[\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}-\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]
    {[J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)]\times[J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)(k\pm2)]}^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\bigskip
Suggested edits
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\label{key2}
E_{k,k}&=& \tfrac{1}{2}
    [\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}+\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]J(J+1)
    +\bigl( \mathcal{B}_{z}^{(e)} -\tfrac{1}{2}
    [\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}+\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]
    \bigr)\kappa^{2}  \\
E_{k\pm2,k}&=& \tfrac{1}{4}
    [\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}-\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]
    [J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)]\times
    \bigl[J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)(k\pm2)\bigr]^{1/2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\bigskip
Solution that uses an \texttt{align} environment
\begin{align}\label{key3}
E_{k,k} &= \tfrac{1}{2}
    [\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}+\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]J(J+1)
    +\bigl( \mathcal{B}_{z}^{(e)} -\tfrac{1}{2}
    [\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}+\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]
    \bigr)\kappa^{2}  \\
E_{k\pm2,k} &= \tfrac{1}{4}
    [\mathcal{B}_{x}^{(e)}-\mathcal{B}_{y}^{(e)}]
    [J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)]\times
    \bigl[J(J+1)-k(k\pm1)(k\pm2)\bigr]^{1/2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```